# checking return type scanner object java two inputs

Tags: java

say if I had a scanner object taking in two inputs

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


int number1 = console.nextInt();
int number2 = console.nextInt();
```

and the number2 input I validate with a `!= // some number`

but for the number1 input I want to validate by not of type int.
how would I do that?
such as something like `number1 != //type int`

Comment: was making a simple console program that asks a user for two different numbers like 22 10. that way number1 = 22 an number2 = 10. I made a simple program before that got scanner input and checked if a user enter a string instead of a int by using !console.hasNextInt() but I'm like how do I do that now with two inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanners don't actually deal in typed values. They get a whole bunch of bytes, convert them to Strings, then parse them into whatever you ask for.

To check the "type" you can just get the next token using `console.next()` then check if it's an integer by looping through it and checking if every character is `0-9`.

Technically, you'd then want to make sure that it isn't `> Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `< Integer.MIN_VALUE` by parsing it as a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with try/catch statement:

```
int number1;
try {
    number1 = console.nextInt();
} catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
    ...
}
```